# You are not authorized to access this page

Tags: drupal-7

When I click on apply button at the following url:

```
http://www.sinepulse.com/job-open-list
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
  Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

If I log in and try again it works. It seems to change some permission, but it kills my whole day. Any drupal expert? I study lot of article related to this topic but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggestions, check the permission of the views and check that you set it to anonymous users could see your views, and another guess is your content is not published and users don't allow to see the unpublished contents.